# how to get the list of all user status(login or logout) using their ID in wordpress using php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

//i want to display the status(login or logout) of selected user id in //wordpress using php

```
 <?php 
/**
 * Capture user login and add it as timestamp in user meta data
 *
 */

function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
```

/**
   * Display last login time
   *
   */

```
function wpb_lastlogin() 
 { 
    $last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login');
    $the_login_date = human_time_diff($last_login);
    return $the_login_date; 
 } 

 /**
 * Add Shortcode lastlogin 
 *
 */

 add_shortcode('lastlogin','wpb_lastlogin');
?>

//i want this kind of code for all users
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are trying to have a meta value of user set once the user is logged in is quite good.

You have to reset that value to null once the user logout again.

Now, you can look for the values of that meta and show "Logged In" if the user meta has some value set by you and if not then "Logged Out" is shown.

Furthermore, you can check user last login time to be difference of more than 5 min not updated since some time user doesn't logout and directly close the site.